# Google Calendar API - Modifying optParams

Tags: arrays, parameters, google-api, reorderlist

I finally managed to get my events out of the google calendar, but a executive decission was made and it was to switch the list of events around so that the last event is first on-screen. I think that the easiest way would be to change the optParams 'orderBy' to something other than startTime. So that it arrieves in descending order instead. But I have no idea how to alter this, so thats why I am here. If anyone have a way to flip the gianorums array around, then that is fine too. 
It might be a bit too little to work with, but if you have done this before, you might know what I mean. Otherwise, please just leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible late, but my coarse of action with objects and displaying results is to have an array in between. In this case I would use

```
$eventList = $service->events->listEvents($calendar->getId() , $optParams);
```

then I would use this:

```
foreach($eventList->getItems() as $event) {
        $eventArray[]=$event->getSummary();
    }
```

And then this:

```
$reverseEventArray = array_reverse($eventArray, false);
```